# PyMySQL: How to implement Bulk INSERT query with prepared statements?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

How do I use prepared statements for MySQL Bulk Inset like below:

```
insert into multi(c1,c2,c3)

 VALUES 

( 1,'hey','{"name": "Jon", "Age": 20}' ),

( 2,'hi','{"name": "Doe", "Age": 20}' )
```

I tried `recs.append("( {0},'{1}','{2}' )".format(2, '%s', '%s'))` but it will not work as I will not have dynamic values at run time.

I am using `PyMySQL`

Comment: Have a look at the `executemany` method.

Comment: @match that stills insets individually